# iOS 8 App Extension and Host App in separate project files. Is it possible in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, ios-app-extension

Currently we're using premake5 to generate our project files, as we develop multi-platform. Obviously we don't need premake to know anything about the extension (as it's iOS8 exclusive feature) but we're facing a problem: Every time we regenerate the main app project file (which happens sometimes) we're forced to manually add all the files and configure the extension, which is dull and error-prone.

Is there a way to add the app extension (a Today Widget) to a separate project? Pbxproj files aren't version control friendly as its contents seem to be shuffled every time you save. So, saving a patch file with all the changes needed doesn't seem like an alternative.

I know this is a broad question about a convenience issue, maybe seasoned Xcode devs know some trickery (or maybe it's just something obvious we're missing here).

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Would love to know this too. App extensions are simply bundles so there is no reason they should be limited to only a target.

Comment: As of today I still don't know if it's possible. Haven't tested with lastest Xcode versions, as I was moved from that project, and then I switched jobs.